# PHP Include performance

Tags: php, performance, include

I have several php-functions in external .php-files (about 50) and I'm including them every time you visit a page - no matter if this function is used or not. I read that this doesn't have any bad consequences on performance.

```
foreach (glob("php_scripts/*.php") as $filename) {
    include $filename;
}

foreach (glob("php_scripts/*/*.php") as $filename) {
    include $filename;
}
```

Now I made some testings regarding performance and found out that including all those files takes approximately 0.0388ms, which is actually about 30 % of whole site execution time.

Then I tried putting all those functions in one php-file and now it takes about 0.01ms, so nearly 4-times faster.

I don't really like this solution because of bad organisation this way. I liked how every function has its own php file and was included automatically. Especially when I use different directories for different types of functions.

Is there any other way I can speed up those includings? Or would it be best to put them all in one file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Include all functions in the php file I need or just the functions I need?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547679/include-all-functions-in-the-php-file-i-need-or-just-the-functions-i-need)

Comment: Also note that every character added (and loaded) means more memory (RAM) consumed and that negatively impacts the number of consecutive requests your hardware can serve.

Comment: I also do `cat includes/*php > all-includes.php` for some projects; given that they are properly enclosed in `<?php` *and* `?>`.